# Whats the right way of managing transactions in Reactive Programming?

Tags: java, transactions, rx-java, reactive

During synchronous method calls, we know how to manage transactions, for eg. we have @Transactional annotation in Spring Boot. But, how can we manage transactions in Reactive Programming (eg. RxJava), particularly when the method calls could be asynchronous?